# Expand element and contract element with animation, according to text size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

The included snippet does almost all of what I want to do.

Click on the 'Toggle expanded' to see the elements expand to the larger size and then contract to the smaller size.

I have a few questions:

1. How can I contract the element whilst still filling it with text (not reducing the text to two lines until the end of the animation)?
2. Is it possible to achieve everything without needing to set the precise width and height in CSS that I am setting?  It is currently fragile to style changes.
3. Is it possible to animate these boxes and have the text 'animate' as well?  e.g. *see* the text re-wrapping as the boxes increase in size

Thanks!

```js
$('#expand-link a').on('click', function(event) {
  var $sections = $('.block');
  if ($sections.data('expanded')) {
    $sections.find('li').each(function() {
      $(this).css('height', this.scrollHeight);
    });
    $sections.removeClass('expanded');
    $sections.find('li').each(function() {
      $(this).css('height', $(this).find('p:not(.fullview)').outerHeight() + 32);
    });
    $sections.removeClass('expandit');
    $sections.data('expanded', false);
  } else {
    $sections.find('li').each(function() {
      $(this).css('height', this.scrollHeight);
    });
    $sections.addClass('expanded');
    $sections.find('li').each(function() {
      $(this).css('height', this.scrollHeight);
    });
    $sections.addClass('expandit');
    $sections.data('expanded', true);
  }
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.expanded li {
  width: 570px;
}
li:first-child {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.section p {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.expanded .section p {
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
}
ul {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.section p.fullview {
  display: none;
}
.expanded .section p.fullview {
  display: block;
}
.block {
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
}
.block.expandit {
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="expand-link">
  <a href="#">Toggle expanded</a>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <ul class="sections">
    <li class="section">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mattis massa mauris. Fusce vel efficitur elit. Curabitur finibus sagittis nisl. Nullam luctus, magna sed feugiat scelerisque, nunc sem facilisis enim, sed ornare nulla urna sit amet
        lectus. Praesent facilisis efficitur ipsum sed gravida. Mauris mollis ut nisi at fringilla. Aenean et orci libero. Curabitur pharetra odio ornare metus pharetra aliquet. Nunc nisl lorem, tempus vitae libero a, feugiat viverra dui.</p>
      <p class="fullview">Some extra content</p>
      <p class="fullview">A bit more</p>
    </li>
    <li class="section">
      <p>Some different less useful text</p>
      <p class="fullview">A bit of extra content for your information</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Would it be okay if I were to reprogram some portions of your code? In it's current state, it would be messy to change too much.

Comment: Absolutely - I'd love to see alternative solutions.  I can't tell if I can use a solution until I see it.